# No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0']

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to train my model with an **image dataset** with this code :

```
import tensorflow as tf

output_size = 10
hidden_layer_size = 50

model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (200, 200, 3)),
                             tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (200, 200, 3)),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense (hidden_layer_size, activation = 'relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense (hidden_layer_size, activation = 'relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense (output_size, activation = 'softmax')])

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
num_epochs = 10
batch_size = 100

model.fit(train_img,
          epochs = num_epochs,
          validation_data = test_img,
          verbose = 2)
```

each time i run the **fit** command the **error** bellow pops up and i couldn't solve it :

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0']
```

Comment: what is your tensorflow version? and why did you put two `Flatten` layers? You would just need one.

Comment: my tensorflow version is 2.3.0 and about the seconde Flatten layer, i forgot to remove it.

Comment: Does your `train_img` also contain the target labels?

Comment: yes it does contain target labels

Comment: what is `train_img`? if list, what is element? if element is numpy array, what is the shape?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to pass dataset as `x` and `y` params to `.fit(...)`. As you said your `train_img` contains target label, you can fix by `x=train_img[0]`, `y=train_img[1]`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

output_size = 10
hidden_layer_size = 50

model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (200, 200, 3)),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense (hidden_layer_size, activation = 'relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense (hidden_layer_size, activation = 'relu'),
                             tf.keras.layers.Dense (output_size, activation = 'softmax')])

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
num_epochs = 10
batch_size = 100

model.fit(x = train_img[0],  // np.random.rand(100, 200, 200, 3)
          y = train_img[1],  // np.random.randint(100, 10)
          epochs = num_epochs,
          validation_data = test_img,
          verbose = 2)
```

According to the doc,

```
Input data. It could be:
A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs).
A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).
A dict mapping input names to the corresponding array/tensors, if the model has named inputs.
A tf.data dataset. Should return a tuple of either (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).
A generator or keras.utils.Sequence returning (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights). A more detailed description of unpacking behavior for iterator types (Dataset, generator, Sequence) is given below.
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit

Comment: Good to hear that. I think in older version of tf.keras or keras, you could pass like that. fit API has changed. could you accept this answer?

Comment: @GhofranChallouf Welcome to SO. Please follow this guideline. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers